# Installing a new distribution of Python on Fedora

Tags: python, linux

I have a Fedora virtual machine.  It comes with Python pre-installed.  I've read that it's not a good idea to uninstall it.  I want to install a different version of Python, Enthought Python.  Should I try to uninstall the existing Python installation and how would I do that?  Should I instead install Enthought Python to a new directory?  Will that be a problem with the existing Python installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not try to uninstall the pre-installed Python.

Install other Python interpreters side by side (in different directories).

You may come across an option to choose the default Python interpreter for your system. Don't change that from the pre-installed one, as that may break some important scripts used by the system. Customize the default Python interpreter for your user only, not for the entire system. (I don't have a Fedora at hand so don't know how that works exactly.)

Also have a look at `virtualenv` for having multiple isolated Python environments with their independent collection of Python modules, and `pythonbrew` for installing multiple Python interpreters.